# Does "used to" refer to a specific time frame?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

Does "used to" refer to a specific time frame?

> I became close friends with Tim in 1999. Although he lived in New York at the time, **I used to** pay him a visit whenever I traveled New York. This one time in 2000, I was even invited to his house for dinner.

When I state events in their chronological order and throw in "use to" somewhere between, is that grammatically correct? I'm not sure if "used to" refers to specific events like simple pasts do.

Comment: 1. You need a preposition of some sort between "traveled" and "New York". 2. There's no contradiction between him living in New York and you visiting him when you travel through New York, so "Although" doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

*Used to* (pronounced *'yoosta'* [justə]) is a quasi-modal which signifies the same habitual or repetitive sense of past actions as the simple present does for present actions:

> Tim **is** living in New York, and I **visit** him whenever I **am** there.
>   Tim **was** living in New York, and I **used to** visit him whenever I **was** there.

*Would* can be used with the same significance:

> Tim **was** living in New York, and I **would** visit him whenever I **was** there.

But *would* of course has many other uses.

In the context of a narrative, *used to* is deployed like any other past tense:

> I was still in college in Boston. Tim was living in New York, and I used to visit him whenever I was there, often on the way back to Nashville where Jane was in school. Once I even stayed at his house for a couple of days. After Jane and I married, however, we moved to Wisconsin, and I lost touch with Tim for many years.

Answer (score 0):

[Used to](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/used+to) is used when something happened frequently or continuously during a period in the past. It is grammatically correct to use it in the sentence you quote; the fact some facts are described in their chronological order doesn't make the use of *used to* less correct.